# Como trabalhar com tabela associativa com atributos adicionais em REST?

Tags: rest, restful

Imagine que você tenha 3 entidades: Aluno, Disciplina e AlunoDisciplina.

A entidade `AlunoDisciplina` , além de relacionar o `Aluno` com a `Disciplina`, também inclui outras informações, como a nota final do aluno. Logo basicamente temos algo assim:

```
class AlunoDisciplina {
    Aluno aluno;
    Disciplina disciplina;
    double notaFinal;
}
```

Da maneira como está exposta a entidade acima, `aluno` e `disciplina` compõem uma chave primária composta, dado que um aluno não pode estar associado à mesma disciplina mais de uma vez.

Algumas operações que eu preciso implementar:

1. Lista de alunos matriculados na disciplina (com as respectivas notas);
2. Lista de disciplinas em que o aluno está matriculado (com as respectivas notas);
3. Adicionar/Remover um aluno de uma disciplina;
4. Editar a nota final do aluno na disciplina.

***Como posso expor este relacionamento de forma RESTful?***

---

#### O que pensei até o momento

Para os itens 1 e 2, respectivamente, imagino os recursos abaixo.

***(GET)*** **/disciplinas/{idDisciplina}/alunos-matriculados.json**

```
{
    "alunosMatriculados": [{
        "aluno": {
            "id": 2,
            "nome": "Pedro"
        },
        "notaFinal": 9.5
    }, {
        "aluno": {
            "id": 6,
            "nome": "Maria"
        },
        "notaFinal": 10
    }]
}
```

***(GET)*** **/alunos/{idAluno}/disciplinas.json**

```
{
    "matriculadoNasDisciplinas": [{
        "disciplina": {
            "id": 1,
            "nome": "Matemática"
        },
        "notaFinal": 9.5
    }, {
        "disciplina": {
            "id": 2,
            "nome": "Filosofia"
        },
        "notaFinal": 7
    }]
}
```

Para os itens 3 e 4 não estou encontrando a melhor forma de resolver.

***A melhor solução seria esta mesmo ou existe alguma outra maneira melhor?***

***Têm alguma sugestão para os itens 3 e 4?***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

acredito que você possa simplificar os retornos dos métodos 1 e 2, retornando apenas uma lista ao inves de um objeto complexo, acredito que isto simplificaria a sua API

(GET) /disciplinas/{idDisciplina}/alunos-matriculados.json

```
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "nome": "Pedro"
        "notaFinal": 9.5,
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "nome": "Maria"
        "notaFinal": 10
    }
]
```

(GET) /alunos/{idAluno}/disciplinas.json

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "nome": "Matemática",
        "notaFinal": 9.5
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "nome": "Filosofia",
        "notaFinal": 7
    }
]
```

Para remover, adicionar uma ou atualizar uma nota, você pode usar a mesma URL porém com Method Definitions diferentes.

```
(POST) /alunos/disciplinas/
C. Body: idAluno=?&idDisciplina=? 
(DELETE) /alunos/disciplinas/
C. Body: idAluno=?&idDisciplina=? 
(PUT) /alunos/disciplinas/
C. Body: idAluno=?&idDisciplina=?&notaFinal=?
```

**Lembrando que isto é apenas uma sugestão**

Comment: Eu adicionaria (POST) /disciplinas/{idDisciplina}/{idAluno} também para adicionar um aluno à disciplina, como uma rota alternativa talvez

Comment: @TobyMosque, na sua sugestão ficaria (POST) `/alunos/1/2`, certo? Não fica um pouco confuso os 2 ids da forma como estão?

Comment: José, realmente isto foi uma falha minha, atualizei a resposta para passar esta informação no Content Body.